# Setup checkerboard colors in Blender UI

Tags: interface, customization

I'm having a problem with default **checkerboard colors** used by Blender in the Image Editor for transparent images. They are too dark. When I render something with **transparency**, I can not evaluate brightness appropriately.

How can I setup those colors and/or checkerboard cell sizes?
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?372962-How-to-change-the-image-viewer-color-for-transparent-pixels
The answer given here is "The checker color cannot be changed in the theme settings" so, what are the options?

Comment: There are no such options to change this. I could imagine the only way to change the color is to edit the source code.

Comment: Edit: I found out that there have been some bugs recording to this matter where they do't display at all, I assume a reason why you change it because they are OpenGL driven.

Comment: Since you can' change these colors, one of the following might help. Overlay the render over another checker image (your own or from the compositor). Use rgb mode to preview alpha as black.